# Calendar event saved locally on phone, but can't sync to Google Calendar

Tags: android, synchronization, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I try to add a calendar by the following code. The event created can be read by calendar apps on my phone, but just sync to online Google Calendar. Can any one give me some hits to solve the issue?

here are some remark
1. Code was run on my real phone (Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1)
2. All other calendar events can sync to Google Calendar, just the program-added cannot be sync.

---update---

When I change the follow code

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_EVENTS,1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.VISIBLE, 1);
```

--
I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only the provider may write to sync_events
```

---

```
    public void addEvent() {

    long startMillis = 0;
    long endMillis = 0;

    Log.v("LOG", "entered addEvent");


    //Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    //beginTime.set(2012, 8, 11, 22, 0);
    //startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + (3600 * 1000)*4;

    //Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    //endTime.set(2012, 8, 11, 23, 0);
    //endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
    endMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + (3600 * 1000)*5;

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Dog");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "DogInDESCRIPTION");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "eventTimezone");

    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_EVENTS,0);      


    cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't set `CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_EVENTS` on `CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI`.

If the calendar is already setup as visible and synchronzed on your device, you can just add an event, and it will synchronize.

If you need to turn the sync on from the app you can set `CalendarContract.Events.SYNC_EVENTS` on `CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI`.

For example (`calId` is the id of the calendar you want to update to be visible and synchronise).

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);

cr.update(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Calendars.CONTENT_URI, calId), values, null, null);
```